# CSS overlapping from divs

Tags: css

i made a php to get posts. And if the post have mkre than 500 texts. The text overlaps from the border and only prints 1 line. I want it to stop from over lapping.

```
div{
    border: 1px solid #ededed;
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
.yourDivClass {
    overflow: auto;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    word-break: break-word;
}
```

Comment: Thanks i will try that later.